# Flex Ul with active li : how to hide the bottom on the ul when li is active

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I'm doing a tab with `ul` and `li` in flex. The problem is that when the `li` is selected, the `li` bottom does not disappear even though I have made it transparent.

Here is my code:

```css
.scroll-nav-x {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.scroll-nav-x::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scroll-nav-x.scroll-tabs-x {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroll-nav-x.scroll-tabs-x li {
  overflow: visible;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 53px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  line-height: 41px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: .9px;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  display: block;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  border: none;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-container {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.tab-container.large {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: none;
}

.tab-container .col-md-4 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scroll-nav-x scroll-tabs-x tabs clearfix">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">All</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Others</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-container large">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">
    <div class="row">
      Dummy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I set the list bottom such that when `li` is active, the bottom border covers the `ul` bottom to create a seamless connection between the `ul` and the content area. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by tweaking your CSS sightly.

1. Add a bottom border to the `li` with the same color as the background (in this case #fff)
2. Remove the bottom border on the `ul`
3. Add a border to the top of your tab container, then shift it up underneath the tab list.

This way the tabs will overlap the top of the tabs container and make it look like the tab list item is part of the tab content

```css
.scroll-nav-x {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.scroll-nav-x::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.scroll-nav-x.scroll-tabs-x {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.scroll-nav-x.scroll-tabs-x li {
  overflow: visible;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 53px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -1px; /* Modified line */
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  line-height: 41px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: .9px;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
ul.tabs li:hover{

  border: none;

}
ul.tabs li.active {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom-color: #fff; /* Modified line */
  cursor: default; 
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tab-container {
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.tab-container.large {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* Removed line */
}
.tab-container .col-md-4 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scroll-nav-x scroll-tabs-x tabs clearfix">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">All</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Others</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-container large">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">
    <div class="row">
      Dummy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```